# Javascript window.location.pathname giving out wrong result

Tags: javascript

I am using REST API to create a sidebar "extension" on a already existing site. In my JS code I'm calling window.location.pathname to get a certain path from the site url.
For Example: https://miro.com/app/board/o9J_khy7PQ8=/

the problem is that when I call `window.location.pathname` I get back the pathname from the server where my extension is stored like so: https://hof.claris.sk/miro/layers0.8.7/sidebar.html . So I get back miro/layers0.8.7/sidebar.html.

Is there any way to get back the actual website url / pathname from the window? I'm sure the window url is not my server since it this shows up:
[url picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lJUR.jpg)

I'm using this code to get the window location

```
let pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/')
boardId =  pathArray[2]
```

Here is how the site layout looks, the sidebar is outlined in blue and the link is the actual website underlined in red
[image]

Comment: it is integrated via REST API

Comment: How exactly have you integrated a normal HTML document as a REST API? That doesn't make much sense at all to me; maybe I'm missing something or there's some aspect you haven't included in your question. I don't see anything regarding the support for the creation of a "sidebar extension" in the [Miro REST API documentation](https://developers.miro.com/docs/introduction-to-resp-api), are you sure you're not trying to integrate as a [Web-plugin](https://developers.miro.com/docs/sdk)?

Comment: There's more on the server than just a html, there is a javascript file providing functionality, a html file in which there is javascript integrated too, to provide UI and a CSS file. The call for the window location comes from the html file nevertheless. The other files have nothing to do with this issue, I will provide a screenshot of how this looks so that there's a better idea of what I'm looking for

Comment: I guess this might be a question for the website developer team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're not getting the results you expected from your call to `window.location.pathName` is because the context in which the JavaScript is executed is *not* in Miro itself; rather it's in your page that's hosted on a completely separate domain and path structure.

---

Note: the rest of this answer is predicated on the assumption that you're really only looking for the board ID - as evidenced by your current source code:

```
let pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
boardId =  pathArray[2];
```

---

Fortunately, Miro provides a pretty robust JavaScript SDK that you can use to extract this information yourself at runtime without having to mess around with the manipulation of `window.location.pathname`.

If your app is correctly integrated with the Miro JavaScript SDK, you can re-build the path to the Miro board itself that's leveraging your plugin by calling `await miro.board.info.get()` and extracting the `id` property from the resulting object:

```
const boardInfo = await miro.board.info.get();
const boardId = boardInfo.id; // result: "o9J_khy7PQ8="
```

You might consider re-reading the documentation for the [`Board` object](https://developers.miro.com/reference#board-object) to get a better understanding of this approach.

Answer (score -2):

Try using:  window.location.href

Comment: The OP only wants the path from the URL. The OPs own code more directly addresses the need than `.href` does.

Comment: yes, I need the website URL in some form or another. The issue isn't really it's form (although I need a certain part of the site path). The issue is that I'm unable to get the url at all and the command returns back the url of my extension from my server while running the extension, which as can be seen on the provided screenshot seems to be incorrect